# Time precision issue on comparison in mongodb driver in Go and possibly in other language and other database

Tags: database, mongodb, go, time

I was learning Go and Mongodb, currently using the [alpha official mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver). Although it is in alpha, it is quite functional for basic usage I think. 
But I got an interesting issue on time conversion in this db driver.

Basically, I created a custom typed struct object, and marshaled it to bson document, and then convert the bson document back to struct object.

```
//check github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/bson/marshal_test.go
func TestUserStructToBsonAndBackwards(t *testing.T) {
u := user{
    Username:          "test_bson_username",
    Password:          "1234",
    UserAccessibility: "normal",
    RegisterationTime: time.Now(), //.Format(time.RFC3339), adding format result a string
}

//Struct To Bson
bsonByteArray, err := bson.Marshal(u)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
//.UnmarshalDocument is the same as ReadDocument
bDoc, err := bson.UnmarshalDocument(bsonByteArray)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
unameFromBson, err := bDoc.LookupErr("username")
//so here the binding is working for bson object too, the bind field named username ratherthan Username
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}
if unameFromBson.StringValue() != "test_bson_username" {
    t.Error("bson from user struct Error")
}

//Bson Doc to User struct
bsonByteArrayFromDoc, err := bDoc.MarshalBSON()
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}

var newU user
err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonByteArrayFromDoc, &newU)
if err != nil {
    t.Error(err)
}

if newU.Username != u.Username {
    t.Error("bson Doc to user struct Error")
}

//here we have an issue about time format.
if newU != u {
    log.Println(newU)
    log.Println(u)
    t.Error("bson Doc to user struct time Error")
}
}
```

However since my struct object has a time field, the result struct object contains a less accurate time value than the original. Then the comparison is failed.

```
=== RUN   TestUserStructToBsonAndBackwards
{test_bson_username 1234     0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC   2018-08-28 23:56:50.006 +0800 CST 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC normal }
{test_bson_username 1234     0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC   2018-08-28 23:56:50.006395949 +0800 CST m=+0.111119920 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC normal }
--- FAIL: TestUserStructToBsonAndBackwards (0.00s)
    model.user_test.go:67: bson Doc to user struct time Error
```

So I would like to ask many questions from this.

1. How to compare time properly in this case ?
2. What's the best way to store time in database to avoid such precision issue ? I think the time in database should not be a string.
3. is this a db driver bug ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Times in BSON are represented as UTC milliseconds since the Unix epoch ([spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)). Time values in Go have nanosecond precision.

To round trip time.Time values through BSON marshalling, use times truncated to milliseconds since the Unix epoch:

```
func truncate(t time.Time) time.Time {
    return time.Unix(0, t.UnixNano()/1e6*1e6)
}

...

u := user{
    Username:          "test_bson_username",
    Password:          "1234",
    UserAccessibility: "normal",
    RegisterationTime: truncate(time.Now()), 
}
```

You can also use the [Time.Truncate](https://godoc.org/time#Time.Truncate) method:

```
u := user{
    Username:          "test_bson_username",
    Password:          "1234",
    UserAccessibility: "normal",
    RegisterationTime:  time.Now().Truncate(time.Millisecond),
}
```

This approach relies on the fact that Unix epoch and Go zero time differ by a whole number of milliseconds.

Comment: this works, also, there's a time.Truncate(time.Millisecond) function, https://godoc.org/time#Time.Truncate

Comment: Times in go have nanosecond *precision*. Time *accuracy* is dependent upon the system the program is running on.

Answer (score 4):

You've correctly identified that the issue is one of *precision*.

[MongoDB's `Date` type is](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) "a 64-bit integer that represents the number of **milliseconds**...".

[Golang's `time.Time` type](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) "represents an instant in time with **nanosecond** precision".

As such, if you compare these respective values as golang types you will only get equivalence if the golang Time has millisecond resolution (e.g. zeroes for micro- and nanosecond places).

For example:

```
gotime := time.Now() // Nanosecond precision
jstime := gotime.Truncate(time.Millisecond) // Milliseconds
gotime == jstime // => likely false (different precision)

isoMillis := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-0700Z"
gomillis := gotime.Format(isoMillis)
jsmillis := jstime.Format(isoMillis)
gomillis == jsmillis // => true (same precision)
```